# Cannot run AutoCAD 2008 32-bit on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, autocad

I purchased a Dell notebook and it came with Windows 7 64-bit installed.

Now when I try to install AutoCAD 2008 which is 32-bit, I am unable to do so. I get an error message stating I can't run a 32-bit program on a 64-bit processor.

What do I do?

Comment: Get 64-bit Autocad?

Comment: You *can* run *some* 32-bit programmes on a 64-bit OS but not ALL due to library and other issues. Windows 64-bit is a MESS!

Comment: Have you installed the [service pack for AutoCAD 2008](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/ps/dl/item?siteID=123112&id=10035892&linkID=9240618)? The readme doesn't suggest there is any problem running AutoCAD on Vista 64-bit and I would be surprised if enough changed with Windows 7 to break it. By the looks of it there is a 64-bit version of AutoCAD 2008, are you able to get and install that?

Answer (score 4):

Two issues in hand from experience:

1. Autocad 2008 will not work past XP.  You can install Autocad 2008 on Vista but you will run into issues with the program.  I had to purchase a new OS when I purchased 3DS Max 2010 (an Autodesk product) and I could not run it on XP.
2. The installer for AutoDesk products will ask when you are installing, is it for a 32bit system or 64 bit system, make sure to select the correct one.

I would possibly consider running a virtual machine (such as [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) or activating [XP mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) in Windows 7 if you know how.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: http://www.longbowsoftware.com/Converter.php. it allows installing 32bit versions of AutoCAD to run natively on 64 bit Windows.